# How to trigger some events based on creation of a new list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, remote-event-receiver, webhooks

My scenario: i have a company list,and each time am creating a company,i need some csom to be trigger that create the different document set for that company.
Note: i try the webhook solution but notice it is trigger not matter if any change happens in the list or sublist. I need a way to limit the trigger of events only on creation of a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Event Receivers seem to be a solution. While attaching RER you have to specify **EventType** - ItemAdded should be the one you are looking for. Following article describes how you can attach RER to Host Web [Remote Event Receivers](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers). Sample code can be downloaded as well, so it can be very helpful while creating first RER.

Comment: can you show me the steps to publish this add in